# Extra characters error when using 'sed' in linux

Tags: linux, sed

My coursework involves writing a linux script to 'restore' files from a pseudo trash folder. I've done this, and it looks like it *should* work, but it doesn't. Instead, I get an error that says:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command

but I can't see why, since I don't use the -e expression anywhere in my code. However, my brain's fried from staring at code for so long that it might just be a silly mistake that I can't see. Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = "-n" ]
then

##if command is used with -n, prompts user to enter a new location for the file

  cd ~/my-documents/mydir01/trashbin
  restore=`sed "$2" ~/my-documents/mydir01/locations`
  name=`basename "$restore"`

  echo $name
  echo "Enter new location for this file."
  read loc
  echo $loc
  mv -i `"$name" "$newloc"/"$name"`

else

##file will be restored to its previous location

  cd ~/my-documents/mydir01/trashbin
  restore=`sed "$1" ~/my-documents/mydir01/locations`
  loc=`dirname "$restore"`
  echo $loc
  name=`dirname "$restore"`
  mv $1 $name
fi
```

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think you may have to move your name=`direname "$restore"` in by 2 spaces to keep within the if/fi

Comment: Using the example command you gave in a comment of one answer, the `sed` is called as `sed "NewFile02" ~/my-documents/mydir01/locations` whether `if` is true or not. In which `N` is a valid command, and it does not take argument, the following `e` confuses `sed`. That's where the error comes from. Based on that, I think you don't really understand what `sed` is, or you wouldn't give it such argument.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are you invoking your shell script? The values of $1 and $2 are used by sed, and it looks like that might be where the problem is occurring.

Based on the comments from the original poster, it appears that the desired end goal is to store the location of the original file in ~/my-documents/mydir01/locations, and later retrieve it from there when the file needs to be restored.

One way to do this would be by using a tuple (such as a key-value pair) to store and retrieve this information. For instance, if the original file name is X and the new file name is Y, at the time of the change, you would add "X Y" to the locations file. Later, when you want to restore the file, you would use either X (or perhaps Y) to pick this line from the location file (hint: use grep), and then use awk or perl (example: awk '{print $1}') to pick the first part of the line. Doing this gives you X, which is what you want, since X is the original name of the file.

In summary, this question is really not about sed at all.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm just invoking it with 'restore [filename]'

Comment: Can you share the exact command you are using it, including a specific value for filename that is causing the problem? [Unlike as in python, spacing does not matter in shell scripts.] One other question. One uses sed to perform a pattern edit. What exactly are you accomplishing with <sed "$1" ~/my-documents/mydir01/locations>?

Comment: the command I was testing was: 
`restore NewFile02` 
The sed lines are supposed to retrieve the file's previous filepath and name from 'location' (text file) I tried using grep instead, but I couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: So I see several problems with the solution you're employing and the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: So I see several problems with the solution you're employing and the problem you are trying to solve. When invoked with "-n", I think you are trying to record (in .... locations) the original name of the file that is being moved. Later, you restore the file from there.

Can you elaborate on why you are using sed to do this?

Comment: For the assignment, I was to create scripts that would delete and restore a file to its original location (this is only the restore script, as the others work properly). I'm using sed to record and retrieve the original name and location of the file so that it can be restored correctly. I was originally using grep, but I couldn't get it to work, so someone else suggested using sed instead.

Comment: @user1860676 So, if I'm interpreting the comments right you're invoking `restore NewFile02`, which if you trace the script, eventually calls `sed "NewFile02" ~/my-documents/mydir01/locations`. However, the string `Newfile02` is not a valid `sed` script - it tries to interpret it as an `N` command (append next line), which is followed by the unexpected characters `ewFile02`, which result in the error message. Reporting `-e expression ...` would appear to be an (repeatable) anomaly in `sed`s error reporting...