# restore script in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using Linux through a virtual machine,

for my coursework i have to create 3 scripts, one of they scripts is to restore deleted files to either a location the user puts in or to the original location

here is what i have for my script so far

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" == "-n" ]
then
  cd /root/michael/trash
  restore`grep "$2" cd /root/michael/store`
  filename=`basename "$restore"`
  echo "Where would you like to save the file?"
  read location
  location1=`readlink -f "$location"`
  mv -i $filename "location1"/filename
else
  cd /root/michael/trash
  restore=`grep "$2" cd /root/michael/store`
  filename=`basename "$restore"`
  mv -i $filename "location1" $location
fi
```

but when i try restore the file i get an error saying

```
grep: cd: no such file or directory
mv: cannot move `test' to `': no such file or directory
```

the sricpt now works when i do restore -n 
but it still doesnt work when i do resotre

update of my script it now looks like :

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" == "-n" ]
then
  cd /root/michael/trash
  restore`grep "$2" /root/michael/store`
  filename=`basename "$restore"`
  echo "Where would you like to save the file?"
  read location
  location1=`readlink -f "$location"`
  mv -i $filename "location1"/filename
else
  cd /root/michael/trash
  restore=`grep "$2" /root/michael/store`
  filename=`basename "$restore"`
  mv -i $filename "location1" $location
fi
```

now I'm getting the error:
mv: missing destination file operand after `' when i try to do restore test.txt

Comment: You have already posted http://stackoverflow.com/q/13610821/242583 with almost exactly same code, in fact, you mess up a bit in this one. You should sort out and learn what mistake you have made in previous one before you ask another question if that's really necessary. I suggest you read shell scripting tutorials first.

Comment: actually that wasn't me that posted that look at the name of the post, clearly 2 different people

Comment: Apology. I didn't even bother to read the poster, I just assumed because some clear mistakes. Still, you need to read some tutorial first, if that course is about shell scripting, which I guess it is. The question has nothing much about restore script, but how to fix your mistakes.

Comment: it is now working when i do restore -n but i'm getting the error
mv: missing destination file operand after `test.txt' when i try to do restore test.txt

Comment: One way to debug is to prefix `echo` before the command to see what the command and arguments would be executed. You also need to edit your question and append your current modified script with exact command you run, so people can read what error is generated upon what stuff.

Comment: that should be `"$location1"/$filename`. chen's answer already corrects that part for you.

Comment: you mean change the 2nd `mv -i $filename "location1" $location` to `mv -i $filename "location1"/$filename` ?

Comment: Well no. I was seeing the error in first `mv`. The second `mv` is wrong, just think about that you want to move files from trash to store. Heck, I think it's all wrong, does that script greps a directory? Start over, and start with what you would type in shell prompt and work from that.

Comment: the first part works, when i do restore -n test.txt, it does ask me where i want to restore the file and it does restore the file where i ask it restore it to, but it doesn't work if do restore test.txt
restore test.txt should restore it to the original place

Comment: There is no way first part works. `restore\`grep "$2" /root/michael/store\``, see how the backtick follows right after `restore`?

Comment: i wouldn't have said it was working if it wasn't, i have tried and tested restore -n and it works fine
only problem i having is restore is not working(restore without -n should restore it to its original place)

Comment: The variable $location is set in the first if clause. When this clause isn't run, the variable is undefined. So when you try to use it in the else clause it's just an empty string.

Comment: OK i how have the file being restore however instead of it being restore to its original place its being restored to /root

Comment: OK i now have it fully working, big thanks to everybody that's helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the cleaned up syntax:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" == "-n" ]
then
  cd /root/michael/trash
  restore `grep "$2" /root/michael/store`
  filename=`basename "$restore"`
  echo "Where would you like to save the file?"
  read location
  location1=`readlink -f "$location"`
  mv -i $filename "$location1"/$filename
else
  cd /root/michael/trash
  restore=`grep "$2" /root/michael/store`
  filename=`basename "$restore"`
  mv -i $filename "$location1" $location
fi
```

But unfortunately I am unable to infer what your goal is in the `else` clause; for instance: `mv -i $filename "$location1" $location` : neither `location` or `location1` is defined before use here.

Comment: if i do restore -n filename it should ask me for a location to where i want to restore the file with the -n i should restore the file to the original place

Answer (score 1):

grep expects two arguments, a pattern and a file. You've given it three, a pattern, the command `cd`, and a file. `cd` is not needed here.