# restore in linux bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Help needed. This is script that I use to perform a restoration of a file from dustbin directory to its original location. It was located before in root. Then using other script it was "deleted" and stored in dustbin directory, and its former location was documented in storage file using this:

```
case $ans in
    y) echo "`readlink -f $1`" >>home/storage & mv $1 /home/dustbin ;;
    n) echo "File not deleted." ;;
    *) echo "Please input answer." ;;
esac
```

So when using the script below I should restore the deleted file, but the following error comes up.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" == "-n" ] ; then
    cd ~/home/dustbin
    restore="$(grep "$2" "$home/storage")"
    filename="$(basename "$restore")"
    echo "Where to save?"
    read location
    location1="$(readlink -f "$location")"
    mv -i $filename "$location1"/$filename
else
    cd ~/home
    storage=$home/storage
    restore="$(grep "$1" "$storage")"
    filename="$(basename "$restore")"
    mv -i $filename $restore
fi
```

error given - `mv: missing file operand`

EDIT:

so okay, I changed my script to something like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $1 ] ; then

    cd ~/home
    storage=~/home/storage
    restore="$(grep "$1" "$storage")"
    filename="$(basename "$restore")"
    mv -i "$filename" "$restore"

fi
```

and still I get error:

mv: cannot stat `filename': No such file or directory

Comment: Add `echo "<$filename> <$restore>"` before the 2nd `mv` line (and similarly to the first one) to see what's going on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [restore script in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615100/restore-script-in-linux)

Comment: please learn how to use the search feature here on StackOverflow. `[bash] restore file` returns numerous questions that have already been answered. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do some basic error handling to see if `$filename` exists before you use it as part of `mv`:

For example, before:

```
mv -i $filename "$location1"/$filename
```

You should probably do a:

```
if [[ -e "$filename" ]]; then
    # do some error handling if you haven't found a filename
fi
```

The `-e` option checks whether the next argument to `[[` refers to a filename that exists. It evaluates to true if so, false otherwise. (Alternatively, use `-f` to check if it's a regular file)

Or at least:
    if [[ -z "$filename" ]]; then
        # do some error handling if you haven't found a filename
    fi

The `-z` option checks whether the next argument to `[[` is the empty string. It evaluates to true if so, false otherwise.

Similar comment about: `mv -i $filename $restore` in your `else` clause.

[Here's a list of test options.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_%28Unix%29)

Comment: so okay, I tried it like this... if [[ -e "$filename" ]] ; then mv -i $filename "$location1"/$filename fi . Did I understand that bit correct? also tried -z and -f. after performing restore filename, then mv: cannot stat `filename': No such file or directory. however it is located in the dustbin directory.

Comment: the suggestion of comment #1 gave me a display of this message: <filename> </root/filename> , what does that mean?

Comment: @RihardsDobelis a lot of details are missing from your question, such as where exactly the files are, and how you are invoking your script (and what arguments you are passing to it)

Comment: My task contains 3 scripts. 1 script is to delete files (moves them from any directory to dustbin directory and stores their old location in to "storage" file which is located in home dir. script 2 which is trash clears the dustbin directory. script 3 the restore should restore the files from dustbin directory to their original directory obtain the last location of the file from storage file. I hope I made myself understandable!

Comment: Still struggling! need help!

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
cd ~/home
```

and

```
mv -i "$filename" "$restore"
```

while the file is located in the dustbin directory, therefore, it is not found.
Do either

```
cd ~/home/dustbin
```

or

```
mv -i "dustbin/$filename" "$restore"
```

or just do

```
mv -i "~/home/dustbin/$filename" "$restore"
```

and drop the `cd`.